# Syntax error calling HANA stored procedure in HANA with JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, hana

I am getting a syntax error calling a HANA stored procedure.  In the SQL editor in Hana Studio it works, but the syntax must be different for the prepareCall in Java.  I think it's the forward slash after the package name, but not sure what to do about it.

Is it because I created the stored procedure under the Content folder?  Should it be built somewhere else?

Here's the connection and call.  The connection is fine

```
            Class.forName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");

            String url = "jdbc:sap://10.9.9.139:30015/GL1";
            String user = "userid";
            String password = "password";

            cn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            if (cn == null) {
                System.out.println("failed");
            }

            cs = cn.prepareCall("call '_SYS_BIC'.'myPackaged/ZMM_PR_MATERIALS_GET'"); <---- THROWS EXCEPTION BELOW
            rs = cs.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(0));
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

// this WORKS FINE... i get a connection and get some records.    
//          rs = cn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA.ORDERS");
//          int i = 0;
//          while (rs.next()) {
//              System.out.println(String.format("rec %2d: %s=%2s", ++i, "ORDER_ID", rs.getString("ORDER_ID")));
//          }



com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "_SYS_BIC": line 1 col 6 (at pos 6)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.createException(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:334)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.generateDatabaseException(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:174)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.packet.ReplyPacket.buildExceptionChain(ReplyPacket.java:104)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.execute(ConnectionSapDB.java:1106)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.CallableStatementSapDB.sendCommand(CallableStatementSapDB.java:1961)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.StatementSapDB.sendSQL(StatementSapDB.java:972)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.CallableStatementSapDB.doParse(CallableStatementSapDB.java:253)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.CallableStatementSapDB.constructor(CallableStatementSapDB.java:212)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.CallableStatementSapDB.<init>(CallableStatementSapDB.java:123)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.CallableStatementSapDBFinalize.<init>(CallableStatementSapDBFinalize.java:31)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.prepareCall(ConnectionSapDB.java:1295)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.trace.Connection.prepareCall(Connection.java:318)
    at com.glazers.hana.utils.HanaStoredProcedure.execute(HanaStoredProcedure.java:54)
    at com.glazers.hana.utils.HanaStoredProcedure.main(HanaStoredProcedure.java:20)
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing it with `{call <your stored procedure>}` as that is the JDBC escape which the driver converts to the server specific format. Also you use `'` as a quote for the identifiers, in most database implementation the quote for quoted identifiers is a double quote (`"`), or sometimes a backtick (`\``). A single quote is generally reserved for string literals.

Comment: Hi... yes.. I've tried it 100 ways.. no quotes/yes quotes, no package, yes package..... no quotes at all.... no schema, yes schema... every conceivable yes/no I can think of I've tried. Is it not possible thqt SAP have ONE example of calling a stored procedure that is explained and works?  just ONE... I'm using the hana client jar, ng*.jar.  I'm really tired of SAP bragging about the sea of help they have.  It's a joke.  It's nothing.  Calling a stored procedure into HANA ought to be stupid-simple.  It's the package syntax that's the problem I think.  So, what's the syntax?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know HANA, so I can't help you there (and googling doesn't seem to turn up useful information).

Comment: I appreciate your reply and effort.  I'll stay on it.  There is an answer.  When I do I'll return and put it here.  It's a great thing to be able to access Hana via Java calls.  It can be done, and I want to do it.  Thanks again.  It's something so simple, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my stored procedure call is that I didn't escape the double quotes.  The syntax still needs the double quotes in order to properly handle the package and the forward slash.  @Mark Rotteveel, you were close.    I don't get to substitute single quotes for double quotes.  This is what worked: cn.prepareCall("call \"_SYS_BIC\".\"myPackaged/ZMM_PR_MATERIALS_GET\"")